# ExpirationCounter in subscription resource

Tags: onem2m

There is an attribute called *expirationCounter* in subscription resource with following details in TS-0001:
"This attribute (notification policy) indicates that the subscriber wants to set the life of this subscription to a limit of a maximum number of notifications. When the number of notifications sent reaches the count of this counter, the ***subscription*** resource shall be deleted, regardless of any other policy."

Should *expirationCounter* be decreased by the count equal to number of *notificationURI* present in a ***subscription*** and when notification is successfully received by the receiver?

For example:
 a  has 4 *notificationURI* and *expirationCounter* set to 100. when an event occurs, notification is successfully received by 2 URI while 2 *notificationURI* couldn't be reached.

What will be the value of *expirationCounter* in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TS-0001, section 10.2.10.7 „Notification message handling procedure“ the procedure is described in detail. Here it says

> The expirationCounter shall be decreased by one when the Hosting CSE successfully sends the notification request to Receiver(s). If the counter reaches zero, the corresponding subscription resource shall be deleted.

This means that the *expirationCounter* is decreased by one for each notification event and when it could successfully send the requests, not for each request it sends to one or more receivers. It is independent from the number of URI in *notificationURI*.

For example, when a subscription‘s *expirationCounter* is set to 10, then the subscription is removed after the 10th time it is triggered (assuming the requests could be successfully sent).

Comment: Thanks..It is clear to understand from the section you highlighted but confusing to understand from the description given in subscription resource.

Comment: So as you described it is more about processing of a subscription on a successful event resulting in atleast one successful notification.